# enable to initialize other python module before first request (Django + mod_wsgi + apache)

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, python-3.5

I am pretty new to web applications and recently working on a simple demo system using Django + mod_wsgi.
the project looks like this:

```
django/
    |- manage.py
    |- mysite/
    |    |- url.py
    |    |- setting.py
    |    |- wsgi.py
    |- myapp/
         |- views.py
         |- taggers.py
         |- ...
```

and here is the *myapp.conf* configuration

```
WSGIDaemonProcess init python-home=/usr/local/.../3.5.0 python-path=/usr/local/.../django
WSGIProcessGroup init
WSGIImportScript /usr/local/.../django/mysite/wsgi.py process-group=init application-group=%{GLOBAL}
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /usr/local/.../django/mysite/wsgi.py
<Directory /usr/local/.../django/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

what this demo do is quite simple. given an input, press a 'compute' button, calculate the result using a pre-loaded machine learning model, which is loaded at the beginning of *views.py*. Loading the machine learning model will get involved with other python modules such as *sklearn* along with some self-made modules located in the same directory such as *tagger.py*. When I test this demo using 'python3 manage.py runserver', everything goes just fine. Django first loads the machine learning model to RAM, which is quite time-consuming, and wait for the incoming requests and then calculates.

But when I use mod_wsgi + apache, I notice that when I start apache, only *wsgi.py* is executed. The machine learning model is not loaded (which means views.py is not yet imported) until the first access of this demo system through a browser. Even though everything looks fine after the first request, I mean there is no need to load the machine learning model for every calculation, I still hope to automatically load the machine learning model right after apache startup.
I've seen someone talking about faking the first request but I really desired to know if there is another solution such as modifying the *wsgi.py*.

To sum up my questions.

1. how should I modify the default *wsgi.py* to import views.py in order to preload the machine learning model (directly import views.py in wsgi.py will lead to errors saying something like 'apps not installed' )
2. if I have no choice but faking a request, where and how should I write it.

Many thanks.

Comment: You should probably move your learning class out of views.py into a separate module that does not import any Django models, and then import that from the wsgi file.

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel, this sounds like a good solution for me. I am going to try it out next Monday in my work place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as Daniel says in the comment and move the code that pre-loads any data into a separate module and invoke it from global scope in the `wsgi.py` script file when it is being loaded.

The configuration you are using will pre-load the `wsgi.py` when the process is started. You can though simplify the configuration to just:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess init python-home=/usr/local/.../3.5.0 python-path=/usr/local/.../django
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /usr/local/.../django/mysite/wsgi.py process-group=init application-group=%{GLOBAL}
<Directory /usr/local/.../django/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Having both the `process-group` and `application-group` options on the `WSGIScriptAlias` directive also triggers force pre-loading of the `wsgi.py` script file on process start and you don't need the separate `WSGIImportScript`.

Comment: Thank you very much Graham for pointing that out. During these self-teaching days I've read numbers of your article which was extremely helpful. For your answer, I am afraid I cannot try it out until next Monday so there maybe a very late 'Accept'.